# Is there a cloudLESS method to sync your files using your phone

Tags: windows-7, phone

Is there a way to sync all your files from phone to PC and vice versa using an app? if so could you please tell me which app does this for us? Thanks :)

Comment: Without the need for any internet connection? I.E. Plug in and use? What kind of phone are you using (This is important, as I don't think Apple allow anything like this, but it might exist)?

Comment: There's BTSync, and maybe syncthing?

Comment: Could run an FTP server on your computer, and use a client on the phone... maybe a better idea for just a few folders though

Answer (score 1):

Try Bitorrent Sync or Just **Sync** now. Download it [here](https://www.getsync.com/features)

Use your **local network**
You don't need the Internet to use Sync. Sync can utilize local networks even if the Internet is down or unavailable. You can even set up a router in a place with zero internet access to share data over a private network.

16x
faster
Shortest path between devices
Sync always finds the shortest path between devices when transferring data. It doesn't matter if those devices are across the room or across the globe. Sync can share files up to 16x faster than cloud services.

Don't send data around the world
With Sync, you never need to upload files to remote servers halfway around the world before sharing. Sync always uses the shortest path between devices. This saves time, especially for massive files, and makes failed uploads a thing of the past.

Very useful. And **Cloudless**

Also **Own Cloud** Which is kind of similar setups your a sever on your home pc. You can read more on it in the link [here](https://owncloud.org/)

**ownCloud** gives you web services under your control. It is a **self-hosted** open source platform with file sync and sharing at its core and available clients for desktop and mobile. The web frontend has apps for **Pictures**, **Calendar**, **Contacts**, **News**/**RSS**, **Bookmarks**, **Notes**, **Music** and much more via an open app platform! 
ownCloud Server can be installed on **Windows** and **Linux** operating systems, and is available via **packages**, **sources**, or a one file php installer.

**Syncthing**

Syncthing **replaces** proprietary **sync and cloud services** with something open, trustworthy and decentralized. Your **data** is your **data** alone and you deserve to choose where it is stored, if it is shared with some third party and how it's transmitted over the Internet.  Grab it [here](https://syncthing.net/)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the suggestion but you know that with Bittorrent Sync, I need to have a pro version in order to automatically sync my files across devices, do you know any other alternatives? Thanks :)

Comment: @Joe Smith Added some more open source Alternatives.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "Addedsome more open source Alternatives"?

Comment: Added some more Alternatives to the Answer.